# Errors when I collect tweets using twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-search

I'm using tweetminer to collect tweets from this site:
https://github.com/kshaffer/tweetmineR

but when I run the search using twitter_search.py
I get those errors:

```
<undefined>
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 196: character maps to <undefined>
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f43c' in position 88: character maps to <undefined>
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u06cc' in position 210: character maps to <undefined>
```

They aren't exactly errors, but the search will continue. But there's a lot of them get printed on the console. How to resolve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add the parameter `encoding='utf-8'` each time you use `open()` (lines 41 and 48). Or apply `.encode('utf-8')` to the tweets you collect.